# Behavior of redirect_to in rescue block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to know if I am understanding the `begin`/`rescue` construct in Ruby correctly. I read the Ruby docs and I am still not sure if I am clear. I'm implementing Stripe for payment in a Rails site I am building. Stripe recommends using `begin`/`rescue`. I have the following code in my payments controller based on stripe.com's docs:

```
begin
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount      => @amount,
    :card        => token,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'usd'
  )
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to charges_path
end

@payment = Payment.new(params[:payment])
if @payment.save
  flash[:notice] = "Payment taken for #{number_to_currency(@amount/100)}."
else
  flash[:notice] = "Payment record not created."
  redirect_to charges_path
end
```

I don't want the section starting with `@payment` that comes after the end of the `begin`/`rescue` to run if the charge to stripe fails. It looks to me that upon failure of the stripe charge, the rescue code will run, causing rails to redirect to the `charges_path` and the following `@payment` code will not run, which is the behavior I want. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: This is a lot of code for the controller. And why don’t you write a test to assert that the behavior you want is indeed what happens?

Comment: This also really has little to do with `rescue` and is more about the behavior of `redirect_to`.

Comment: The controller is where Stripe documentation for rails recommends it to go (all of the code minus the last 7 lines is almost verbatim from the Stripe docs). If not the controller, where would I put this code? Maybe a helper?

Comment: No, not a helper. Some other object that manages the actual charging. Think about what happens when you have to charge somewhere else—you do this all over again? Further, controller methods should be among the shortest, but this one is nearly 20 lines—which is a lot.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Due to my noobie status with rails, the only places I know of to put logic is in the controllers, helpers, models and views. This code certainly doesn't belong in a view and the model doesn't have access to params[]. So, if not the controller or a helper (not even perhaps the application helper?), where could I create that object to handle the charge?

Comment: Anywhere you want. Rails is a framework, not your application. Don’t let it restrict how your application is designed.

Comment: The idea of service objects may be helpful to guide newer Rails developers towards an understanding of how their code may be better organized: https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Add a `return` statement after the `redirect_to`, i.e.

```
return redirect_to(charges_path)
```

*OR*

```
redirect_to(charges_path)
return
```